# Java identifying user in a turn based client server game

Tags: java, server, ip, client

I'm writing on a simple turn based game. The logic is done as well as a server that functions correctly. I just have one minor problem; how can i identify the user of the application?

Right now, if I end the turn, the logic just goes an as if it was a singleplayer game and I can continue playing with player 2 etc. How can I disallow input from the second player while player one makes his turn and vice versa? Also it should always show the cards of the player himself, right now it shows the one of current player (which switches at the end of the turn)

I am implementing server sockets and saw that I can get the IP address of the user, but how can I connect the two then? Should I save the IP address with the player instance and everytime an input comes check if the current players IP is the same as the one that makes the input?

The server works as a broadcaster, both players have the app running and when they end turn, the information is being sent over the server to the other user.

Please let me know if i can provide some specific code, i don't want to post it all here as its way too much information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am implementing server sockets and saw that I can get the IP address of the user, but how can I connect the two then?

The client IP address does not uniquely identify the user.  A pair consisting of the client IP and the client port number would work as a *temporary* identifier.  (But not permanent, a user will *at least* have a different port number each time he / she connects or reconnects, and the IP address could change too.)

You could use a hashmap to map the IP / port pair to a "player" object or name or something.

> Should I save the IP address with the player instance and everytime an input comes check if the current players IP is the same as the one that makes the input?

IP + port.

That would be one way.  Another would be to keep track of which socket / socket input stream you are reading from.

Comment: Hello Stephen, I'm very glad to get your answer, as I already read another one from you about IP (getting IP address of current system). Now, the game will not be saved and is always opened anew, furthermore the connection only needs to work over LAN, so I guess the IP by itself is fine. I tried to save the IP now with the player and then make a check like 'while(!(player[i].getIp() == Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()))) i++;. ' unfortunately this still doesn't seem to work totally. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *"so I guess the IP by itself is fine..."* - Only if you assume that there is one player per computer and nobody is (for example) trying to cheat.

Comment: *`Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`* - That is the IP address of the server machine!!!  You need to use `Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress` and `Socket.getPort`.  Read the javadocs.  Rely on the javadocs rather than adapting random examples that (apparently) are doing something different from to what you are trying to do.